# I am trying to create a BarPlot showing white wins and black wins, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

This is the code that I have, I am using Python 3

how do i take the data from the WhiteWin.txt file and BlackWin.txt file and create a barplot?

```
data = open("LichessFullData2013.txt", 'r')
data_lines = data.readlines()

WhiteWin = open('venv/WhiteWin.txt', 'w')
for line in data_lines:
    if '[Result "1-0"]' in line:
     WhiteWin.write(line)
WhiteWin.close()

BlackWin = open('venv/BlackWin.txt', 'w')
for line in data_lines:
    if '[Result "0-1"]' in line:
        BlackWin.write(line)
BlackWin.close()

import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset("WhiteWins/BlackWins")
x, y, hue = "2013", "Wins", "Win Percentage"
hue_order = ["WhiteWin", "BlackWin"]
(df[x]
    .groupby(df[hue])
 .valye_counts(normalize=True)
 .rename(y)
 .reset_index()
 .pipe((sns.barplot, "data"), x=x, y=y, hue=hue)
```

Comment: the function sns.load_dataset() loads data from the online repository which does not have a "WhiteWins/BlackWins" dataset. Furthermore there is a missing closing bracket in the last line.

Comment: Im trying to get it to read from two txt files I have, I am not quite sure what I am doing right now, first time using python.